# Linear gradient CSS

Tags: css

In a help of you all. I am not new to CSS but new to this problem. I really wanted to use CSS gradient property. But the way I need is that I need to set the gradient from bottom to top and right to left. Simply like scroll bars, in page right and bottom. I have created bottom to top one class and right to left one class. Simpe CSS concept it overwrites with the latest style.

How can I tackle this situation. The way I tried is as below:

```
.bottom_to_top{background: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top, #FFFFFF 95%, #80868E 100%);}
.right_to_left{-webkit-linear-gradient(center left,#FFFFFF 95%, #80868E 100%);}
```

I have called these two classes but simply one is overwritten by another. How can I tackle this situation. No Browser compatibility (Only for Chrome). No need the image usage also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display both gradients you need a semi-trasparency on the top one.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/qpHfe/)

CSS:

```
.bottom_to_top{
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, color-stop(95%, #FFFFFF), color-stop(100%, #80868E));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 95%, #80868E 100%);
}
.right_to_left{
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left center, right center, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)), color-stop(95%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), color-stop(100%, #80868E));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 95%, #80868E 100%);
}​
```

Notice that `.right_to_left` uses `rgba` instead of `hex`. Adjust it to your needings (you can use a simple online generator like [visualcsstools](http://www.visualcsstools.com/)).

Also, for complete Chrome support you need the [double declaration](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) (Chrome<10)

---

Using a single div, with [multiple bgs](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/wXEXM/)

```
.gradients{
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left center, right center, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)), color-stop(95%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), color-stop(100%, #80868E)), -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, color-stop(95%, #FFFFFF), color-stop(100%, #80868E));
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 95%, #80868E 100%),  -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 95%, #80868E 100%);
}
```

​
As you can see the first declaration in the one *in front*, while the second one is the *background*.

Comment: Hi.. this is really awesome.. working really fine.. May be stupid question I am going to ask.. is it difficult to apply both classes to only one div element? Do we really need to use two div elements??

Comment: thanks mate.. this is what I need.. really nice.. I almost spoiled more than 5 hours to find solutions.. :(... thanks to save my time mate..

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your actually only using `-webkit-linear-gradient(center left,#FFFFFF 95%, #80868E 100%);` as you should use

```
-webkit-linear-gradient(center left,#FFFFFF 95%, #80868E 100%);
-o-linear-gradient(center left,#FFFFFF 95%, #80868E 100%);
-moz-linear-gradient(center left,#FFFFFF 95%, #80868E 100%);
```

IE is tricky with gradients, you must use `filter`

Comment: mate.. you better read the question properly... I need it only for Chrome and gradient should be right to left and bottom to top at same time for the particular element I called the class.. not in angle direction.. should be perpendicular to right border of the page and bottom border of the page.. did I confused in question??

Comment: @FaizulHasan sorry, I misunderstood you, I thought that you need it browser compatible.